# Objective C - UIAlertViewDelegate cannot access UILabel in other class

Tags: objective-c, class, delegates, uialertview

I am new to Objective C and having an issue that I know must be a very simple one - I think perhaps I am approaching it the wrong way.

I have created an UIAlertViewDelegate class that I want to be the delegate for some UIAlertViews that I have in my View Controller class.

When the user presses a button and enters some text, I would like a label in my ViewController class to be updated with that text. However, I obviously cannot reference the label "outputLabel" from my UIAlertViewDelegate class unless I pass it in some way.

The error I get is "Use of undeclared identifier 'outputLabel'. "

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>;
...
@property (strong) UIAlertViewDelegate *AVDelegate;
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIAlertViewDelegate *AVDelegate;
    AVDelegate = [[UIAlertViewDelegate alloc] init];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (IBAction)doAlertInput:(id)sender {
    UIAlertViewDelegate *AVDelegate;
    AVDelegate = [[UIAlertViewDelegate alloc] init];

    UIAlertView *alertDialogue;
    alertDialogue = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                 initWithTitle:@"Email Address"
                 message:@"Please Enter Your Email Address:"
                 delegate:self.AVDelegate
                 cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                 otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    alertDialogue.alertViewStyle=UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    [alertDialogue show];
}
```

UIAlertViewDelegate.m

```
#import "UIAlertViewDelegate.h"

@implementation UIAlertViewDelegate

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *buttonTitle = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    NSString *alertTitle = [alertView title];

    if ([alertTitle isEqualToString:@"Alert Button Selected"] || [alertTitle         isEqualToString:@"Alert Button Selected"]) {

    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Maybe Later"])
    {
        outputLabel.text=@"User Clicked: 'Maybe Later'";
```

UIAlertViewDelegate.h

```
@interface UIAlertViewDelegate : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate,UIActionSheetDelegate>;
```

I've done some work many years ago with Java. I imagine I have to pass my UIAlertViewDelegate class the view somehow but Im not sure on the syntax, would greatly appreciate a pointer in the right direction...

James

Comment: @you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688153/ios-beginner-uialertview-window-with-3-buttons-check-what-button-was-pressed look the code in this 'QUESTION'

Comment: "When the user presses a button and enters some text, I would like a label in my ViewController class to be updated with that text."  I'm trying to figure out what you are trying to do here, and what it has to do with an alert view.  What exactly are you trying to do?  I can tell you that you do not have to make a UIAlertViewDelegate class, your view controller will be the delegate for the alert view.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of things here that you shouldn't be doing but, starting with the main ones affecting your question....

You shouldn't be inventing your own `UIAlertViewDelegate` class, which means don't do this...

```
@interface UIAlertViewDelegate : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate,UIActionSheetDelegate>;
```

Because `UIAlertViewDelegate` is a protocol, you also can't use `alloc` with it.

The main thing that's **correct** is...

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

That says that your `ViewController` is able to act as a `UIAlertViewDelegate` and therefore your code for creating the alert can use `delegate:self` instead of trying to create a separate delegate property or object.

You are likely to still have questions but those changes should clean it up a bit.

Comment: Agree with Phillip Mills. Just write this method in your view controller                                                                1) - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex

Comment: Hi both, thanks very much for your quick response. I was actually just doing this as a test. Originally I did have the delegate assigned as self but I wanted to see if I could have an entire separate class that could be the delegate across my entire application. Is this possible? If so, how do you think I should go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Your view controller is the delegate for the alert view, therefore, you don’t need to crate the delegate object.

init the alert view using self (the view controller) as the delegate argument.

You then implement the delegate methods (for the alert view) within the view controller.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html

The point of delegation is to make it possible for an object to have callbacks on any class.

I would suggest reading over protocols and delegation.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH14-SW1

I'm guessing you are trying to use the alert view to input text, so you would set the alert view style to UIAlertViewPlainTextStyle, and setting the label in one of the callbacks by accessing the text field from the alertView object.